# How to properly render arbitrary text content from HTML tree in wffweb

Tags: java, wffweb

The following piece of wffweb java code (relatively close to examples available on [wffweb](https://webfirmframework.github.io) website):

```
        html = new Html(null) {{
            new Head(this) {{
                new TitleTag(this) {{
                    new NoTag(this, "No <tags> inside, please!");
                }};
            }};
        }};

        System.out.println(html.toHtmlString());
```

Prints out:

```
<html><head><title>No <tags> inside, please!</title></head></html>
```

What I expect (and need) is to have any XML characters inside text nodes escaped using corresponding mechanisms (`<tags>` should be `&lt;tags&gt;` in this case).

What is the proper (or a recommended) way to have the XML syntax inside text nodes escaped in the output? I obviously can myself wrap the XML syntax before adding the string, but that doesn't sound right, I shouldn't have to escape/unescape text node values every time, I expect them to be stored as regular strings in the tree, and only modified during serialization.

Answer (score 1):

It can be achieved with the help of `org.apache.commons.text.StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml4` method from [commons-text](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text).

Here is my `XmlUtil` class:

```
import org.apache.commons.text.StringEscapeUtils;

public class XmlUtil {    

    //using StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml4
    public static String convertSymbolsToEntityChars(String text) {
        return StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml4(text);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(convertSymbolsToEntityChars("No <tags> inside, please!"));
    }
}
```

If you run the `main` method it will print `No &lt;tags&gt; inside, please!`
If you prefer *jsoup* way you have to update `ENTITIES_STRING` if you want more entity characters to be supported.

So your final code will look like this:

```
html = new Html(null) {{                                 
    new Head(this) {{                                    
        new TitleTag(this) {{                            
            new NoTag(this, XmlUtil.convertSymbolsToEntityChars("No <tags> inside, please!", true));
        }};                                              
    }};                                                  
}};                                                      

System.out.println(html.toHtmlString());
```

this will now print:

```
<html><head><title>No &lt;tags&gt; inside, please!</title></head></html>
```

---

Please know that `NoTag` supports both plain text and HTML.

`new NoTag(this, "No <tags> inside, please!");` is equalent to

```
//constructor params = (parent, content, contentTypeHtml)
new NoTag(this, "No <tags> inside, please!", false);
```

so if you are passing content which is supposed to be treated as HTML then `new NoTag(this, "No &lt;tags&gt; inside, please!", true);` is the recommended way.

---

As of the latest version of [wffweb](https://webfirmframework.com) the functional style coding is recommended instead of anonymous style coding. Eg:

```
Html rootTag = new Html(null).give(html -> {
    new Head(html).give(head -> {
        new TitleTag(head).give(title -> {
            new NoTag(title, "No &lt;tags&gt; inside, please!", true);            
        });
    });    
});
System.out.println(rootTag.toHtmlString());
```

---

If you want to show `No &lt;tags&gt; inside, please!` only by `toHtmlString` but want to get original unconverted string from the `TitleTag` then you can use `SharedTagContent<String>` instead of `NoTag`. Watch [this video about its usage](https://youtu.be/AKwdJqh7Yj4).

Eg:

```
SharedTagContent<String> titleSTC = new SharedTagContent<>("No <tags> inside, please!", true);                        

Html rootTag = new Html(null).give(html -> {                                                                          
    new Head(html).give(head -> {                                                                                     
        new TitleTag(head).give(title -> {                                                                            
            title.subscribeTo(titleSTC, content -> {                                                                  
                String innerText = content.getContent();                                                              
                if (innerText != null && content.isContentTypeHtml()) {                                               
                    String contentHavingEntityCharacters = XmlUtil.convertSymbolsToEntityChars(innerText);            
                    return new SharedTagContent.Content<>(contentHavingEntityCharacters, content.isContentTypeHtml());
                }                                                                                                     
                return content;                                                                                       
            });                                                                                                       
        });                                                                                                           
    });                                                                                                               
});                                                                                                                   
System.out.println("rootTag.toHtmlString() = " + rootTag.toHtmlString());                                             
System.out.println("titleSTC.getContent() = " + titleSTC.getContent());                                               

//to get unconverted text from TitleTag                                                                               
TitleTag titleTag = TagRepository.findOneTagAssignableToTag(TitleTag.class, rootTag);                                 
String titleTagInnerContent = (String) titleTag.getSharedTagContent().getContent();                                   
System.out.println("titleTagInnerContent = " + titleTagInnerContent);
```

it prints

```
rootTag.toHtmlString() = <html><head><title>No &lt;tags&gt; inside, please!</title></head></html>
titleSTC.getContent() = No <tags> inside, please!
titleTagInnerContent = No <tags> inside, please!
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create your custom class extended by `NoTag`. You also have to use `org.apache.commons.text.StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml4` method to convert special chars to xml entities in it. This is the recommended way because we are extending the functionality of `NoTag`.

Eg:

```
public class EscapeXmlNoTag extends NoTag {

    private final String content;

    public EscapeXmlNoTag(AbstractHtml base, String content) {
        super(base, org.apache.commons.text.StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml4(content), true);
        this.content = content;
    }

    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }
}
```

You can use this `EscapeXmlNoTag` class instead of `NoTag` as follows

```
Html rootTag = new Html(null).give(html -> {
    new Head(html).give(head -> {
        new TitleTag(head).give(title -> {
            new EscapeXmlNoTag(title, "No <tags> inside, please!");
        });
    });
});
System.out.println(rootTag.toHtmlString());
```

prints

```
<html><head><title>No &lt;tags&gt; inside, please!</title></head></html>
```

---

Late binding is also possible if it is handled properly. If the text content is heavy for conversion want to do a parallel operation then it is appropriate. The latest version of *wffweb* is thread-safe. Eg:

```
List<Runnable> tasks = new ArrayList<>();

Html rootTag = new Html(null).give(html -> {
    new Head(html).give(head -> {
        new TitleTag(head).give(title -> tasks.add(() -> new EscapeXmlNoTag(title, "No <tags> inside, please!")));
        new Body(head).give(body -> {
            new Div(body).give(div -> tasks.add(() -> new EscapeXmlNoTag(div, "<div> content goes here")));
        });
    });
});

tasks.parallelStream().forEach(Runnable::run);
tasks.clear();

System.out.println(rootTag.toHtmlString());
```

it prints

```
<html><head><title>No &lt;tags&gt; inside, please!</title><body><div>&lt;div&gt; content goes here</div></body></head></html>
```

In this sample there is only one child (i.e. only the `NoTag`) for `TitleTag` & `Div` so there is no issue of execution order otherwise order of execution of `tasks` needs to be maintained.